# Implementing countries to spinner in activity

Tags: java, android

I am trying to implement: https://github.com/hbb20/CountryCodePickerProject to my project to show a list of all countries in a spinner.

I added code to my build.gradle (app):

```
implementation 'com.hbb20:ccp:2.3.4'
```

After that I added it to XML file (layout) as it state on https://github.com/hbb20/CountryCodePickerProject/wiki/Use-as-a-Country-Selector:

```
<com.hbb20.CountryCodePicker
        android:id="@+id/country"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        app:ccp_showFullName="true"
        app:ccp_showNameCode="false"
        app:ccp_showPhoneCode="false"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />
```

When I run my application it looks like:

[image]

But when I click on the spinner to select country application crash and in Logcat I get an error:

```
2019-12-27 14:47:00.619 13536-13536/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.cryptowallet, PID: 13536
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #78: Binary XML file line #78: Error inflating class com.futuremind.recyclerviewfastscroll.FastScroller
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #78: Error inflating class com.futuremind.recyclerviewfastscroll.FastScroller
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

Comment: Maybe this issue about the same problem https://github.com/hbb20/CountryCodePickerProject/issues/362

I can recommend you also to raise another one. That really looks like a bug in this library.

Comment: Shame, I guess I'll try to found another for countries as this one crashes on 8, 9, and 10 for me. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Add below 2 lines in `gradle.properties` file.

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```